# How can I delete an AddressBookGroup entry?

Tags: objective-c, ios

here is my Code to create a new Group in the Adress Book:

```
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); //create a group 
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", nil); // set group's name 
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, nil); // add the person to the group         
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, nil); // add the group
```

BUT how i can delete this Group (and other) programmaticaly from my App ? Any sample Code ?

Thanks a lot! Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Sample Project [ABUIGroups](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ABUIGroups/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows you how to do this.

It uses this method:

```
    // Remove a group from the given address book
- (void)deleteGroup:(ABRecordRef)group fromAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)myAddressBook
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(myAddressBook, group, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(myAddressBook,&error);
}
```

Comment: @Marv: The quoted code *is* using only native (Apple) methods.

Comment: It's also possible to rename a Group ? Thanks!